# How to make WooCommerce product prices aligned?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

This is how it looks now https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nbD22T8GTjNTa2-qVn7QQrwe2BJV0R3L/view?usp=sharing

I know that I can do this with Minimum height code, but then it just makes big spaces...

Site is https://bonideco.com

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want prices to be aligned, there should be spaces..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fixed height for the cards. Here is the CSS code that might work for your use case -

```
.woocommerce-card__header {
    height: 315px;
}

ul.products li.product .price {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 6%;
}
```